# How to add dictionary to dictionary in plist?

Tags: objective-c

I need to add more than one dictionary to a plist. How can do it?

```
NSMutableDictionary *rootDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
NSMutableDictionary *rowsDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
NSMutableDictionary *itemZeroDict1 = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

I need to add `rowsDict` and `itemZeroDict1` to `rootDict`.

Comment: post the code you use to create or read in the .plist.  Then people can show you how to add the dictionary.

Comment: Please edit your question with relevant code, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: In the future, also [format your code properly](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks!

Comment: Also, it would be best if you'd use complete words, and not “plz”, “u”, etc. It's not a big deal, but a lot of people here (myself included) look down on that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *root = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1" forKey:@"number"],
                      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"2" forKey:@"number"],
                      nil];

NSString *error = nil;
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:root
                                                               format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
                                                     errorDescription:&error];
if (plistData == nil)
    NSLog(@"Error serializing plist: %@", error);
else 
    // Do whatever you want with plistData
[error release];  // this is an exception to the usual memory management in Cocoa
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to write dictionary to .plist file.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask,
                                                             YES);
        NSString *plistPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"friendList.plist"];

/* Code to remove Existing file from Document directory */

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]){
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:plistPath error:nil];
        }
////////////////

        /** Copy Plist file from your bundle resource to Document directory */

        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"friendList" ofType:@"plist"];
        BOOL sucesss = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:plistPath error:nil];
        if (!sucesss) {

        }

        NSMutableArray *arryDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *dict in arryOfDictionary) {

            NSDictionary *dictFriend = @{@"key":@"value"};

            [arryDict addObject:dictFriend];
        }

        [arryDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:NO];
```